# Let $(X,\mathcal{F},\mu)$ be a measure space and let $g\in L^1((X,\mathcal{F},\mu))$.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $\phi:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$\displaystyle \phi(t)=\int_X \frac{t^3g}{1+t^2g^2}\ \mathsf d\mu$$ Show that $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)\subset\mathbb{R}$ and that $\phi$ is continuous.

To show that $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)\subset\mathbb{R}$ I did this:

Note that $$\displaystyle \frac{|g|}{|1+t^2g^2|}=\frac{|g|}{1+t^2g^2}\leq |g|,$$ because $1+t^2g^2\geq 1$.

Then, $$\displaystyle |\phi(t)|\leq\left\lVert\frac{t^3g}{1+t^2g^2} \right\rVert_1=|t^3|\left\lVert\frac{g}{1+t^2g^2}\right\rVert_1\leq |t^3|\left\lVert g\right\rVert_1<\infty.$$

Therefore, $\operatorname{Im}(\phi)\subset \mathbb{R}$. (Is that correct?)

And to show that it is continuous, I'm trying to show that it is differentiable by trying to find an integrable $f$ such that $$\displaystyle\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{t^3g}{1+t^2g^2}\right)\right|\leq f,$$ where

$$\displaystyle\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \left(\frac{t^3g}{1+t^2g^2}\right)=\frac{t^2x(t^2x^2+3)}{(t^2x^2+1)^2}.$$ But I can't find such $f$. Is there another way to show it?

A hint would be more appreciated then the whole answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem. You already have a bound on the integrand that is locally uniform in $t$.

Comment: Thanks. And, is the first part of my answer correct?

Comment: Yes .It's absolutely right.